# Movable UserControl in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, mouseevent, move

I created simple `UserControl` with several labels. How can I implement simple mechanism, that allows moving whole control like normal window (when I add it to winForms - if it makes difference)

Comment: Return position of mouse, update UserControl location to mouse position?

Answer (score 2):

You can use my Capture class:

```
public class ClsCapture
{
    bool bCaptureMe;
    Point pLocation = new Point();

    Control dd;
    //Handles dad.MouseDown, dd.MouseDown
    private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        try {
            bCaptureMe = true;
            pLocation = e.GetPosition(sender);
        } catch {
        }
    }

    //Handles dad.MouseMove, dd.MouseMove
    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        try {

            if (bCaptureMe) {
                dd.Margin = new Thickness(dd.Margin.Left - pLocation.X + e.GetPosition(sender).X, dd.Margin.Top - pLocation.Y + e.GetPosition(sender).Y, dd.Margin.Right, dd.Margin.Bottom);

            }
        } catch {
        }
    }

    //Handles dad.MouseUp, dd.MouseUp
    private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        try {
            bCaptureMe = false;
        } catch {
        }
    }

    public ClsCapture(Control pnl)
    {
        dd = pnl;
        dd.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += Form1_MouseDown;
        dd.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp += Form1_MouseUp;
        dd.PreviewMouseMove += Form1_MouseMove;
    }

    public static void CaptureMe(Control pnl)
    {
        ClsCapture cc = new ClsCapture(pnl);
    }

}
```

**Usage:**

```
ClsCapture.CaptureMe(AnyControlYouWant);
```

Comment: I couldn't get System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs